# can't mount a btrfs subvolume - `No such file or directory`

Tags: mount, btrfs

playing around with a btrfs (4.4) machine (server 16.04) I ran into this

#### scenario

ubuntu server 16.04 installed on btrfs with standard subvolumes for `/` and `home`

#### what I want to achieve

put `/var` into it's own subvolume (on the same harddrive for now)

#### what I did

1. `sudo mkdir /subvol`
2. `sudo btrfs subvolume create /subvol/var`
3. `sudo rsync -azv /var/* /subvol/var/`
4. create a line in /etc/fstab for the subvolume (which I have copied from the existing line for the @home subvolume. It looks like this
   `UUID=79a74d84-2f0e-4098-9c58-f721eab913ee  /mnt/var btrfs \ defaults,compress=lzo,subvol=@var   0   2`
5. `sudo mount -a`

#### expected behavior

the new subvolume `var` (located in /subvol/var) get's mounted on `/var`

#### actual behavior

`:~$ sudo mount -a
mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory`

Not sure whether the approach generally is good. It's the idea I could come up with. Any hints what my problem here is?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [btrfs section on the ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#Ubuntu-specific_subvolume_layout_in_11.04_and_later) (presuming that layout is still applicable), the default setup is a btrfs root containing the `@` and `@home` submvolumes.

`/subvol/var` is here presumably created inside the mounted `@` and hence its path relative to the btrfs root (subvolid=5) would be `<FS_TREE>@/subvol/var`, instructions below are based on this assumption.

So you probably either want to move the subvolume to `<FS_TREE>/@var`, via something like

```
mnt -o subvolid=5 /mnt
mv /mnt/@/subvol/var /mnt/@var
umount /mnt
```

and keep the fstab entry as it is.

Or, edit the fstab entry to match the current location

```
UUID=79a74d84-2f0e-4098-9c58-f721eab913ee  /mnt/var btrfs \
defaults,compress=lzo,subvol=@/subvol/var   0   2
```